# Processing special characters

Tags: string, character-encoding, lua

Let's say I receive the following string in Lua `mÜ⌠⌠í∩`and would like to apply it to my current processing code, which is the following

```
function inTable(tbl, item)
    for key, value in pairs(tbl) do
        if value == item then return true end
    end
    return false
end
function processstring(instr)
  finmsg = ""
  achar = {131,132,133,134,142,143,145,146,160,166,181,182,183,198,199,224}
  echar = {130,137,138,144,228}
  ichar = {139,140,141,161,173,179,244}
  ochar = {147,148,149,153,162,167,229,233,234,248}
  uchar = {129,150,151,154,163}
  nchar = {164,165,227,252}
  outmsg = string.upper(instr)
  for c in outmsg:gmatch"." do
    bc = string.byte(c)
    if(bc <= 47 or (bc>=58 and bc<=64) or (bc>=91 and bc<=96) or bc >=123)then
    elseif (bc == 52) then finmsg = finmsg.."A"
    elseif (bc == 51) then finmsg = finmsg.."E"
    elseif (bc == 49) then finmsg = finmsg.."I"
    elseif (bc == 48) then finmsg = finmsg.."O"
    elseif (inTable(achar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."A"
    elseif (inTable(echar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."E"
    elseif (inTable(ichar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."I"
    elseif (inTable(ochar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."O"
    elseif (inTable(uchar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."U"
    elseif (inTable(nchar, bc)==true) then finmsg = finmsg.."N"
    else
    finmsg = finmsg..c
    end
  end
  return finmsg
end
function checkword (instr)
  specword = [[]]
wordlist = {"FIN", "FFI", "PHIN", "PHEN", "FIN", "PHIN", "IFFUM", "MUF", "MEUFEEN", "FEN","FEEN"}
for i, v in ipairs (wordlist) do
  if (string.match(processstring(instr), v) ~= nil)then
    return 1
    end
  end
  --if (string.match(instr,specword) ~= nil)then
  --  return 1
  --end
end
print (checkword("mÜ⌠⌠í∩"))
```

As of now, I have found no way to proof strings like that. Not even by using string.byte() to reduce it to ASCII have I been able to reliably work with exoctic characters like those. Even more weird is that if I do a `print(bc)` on `processstring` I get the folowing output

> 160 226 140 160 195 173 226 136 169

Now, that's 9 ASCII codes for a 6 letter word, how can this be? I built the code referencing http://www.asciitable.com/, is it wrong? How can I approach this processing?

Comment: That word has several non-ASCII letters, they occupy more than 1 byte depending on the encoding. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @YuHao This is basically a word-identifying code. it search for patterns (defined in `wordlist`) and if found returns 1. The `processstring()` function was added to get rid of spaces and so forth, since most messages will use those to deceive the real message. I'm using "muffin" as my test word, so `processstring()` is to avoid things like "m u  f i n" or "m uf1 n" to be misread. However if it still finds nothing, like when the word is "mÜ⌠⌠í∩" I want to do a second check, that support these characters so the code can process these as well. The `elseif`s in `processstring()` also do that.

Comment: This sounds sort-of like you are trying to do collation which is **not** a trivial task and generally requires special UTF-8/etc. libraries to do correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure if collation is the right term (from my limited google knowledge) but collation-ish for sure. I'm starting to feel it's not very trivial, this started as a silly project and but then it built up as people started to beat the word detection and I had to improve the algorithm. Non-ASCII characters is an issue I still haven't solved tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local subst = {
   U = "üûùÜú",
   N = "ñÑπⁿ∩",
   O = "ôöòÖóºσΘΩ°",
   I = "ïîìí¡│",
   F = "⌠",
   A = "âäàåÄÅæÆáª╡╢╖╞╟α",
   E = "éëèÉΣ",
}
local subst_utf8 = {}
for base_letter, list_of_letters in pairs(subst) do
    for utf8letter in list_of_letters:gmatch'[%z\1-\x7F\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]*' do
        subst_utf8[utf8letter] = base_letter
    end
end

function processstring(instr)
  return (instr:upper():gsub('[%z\1-\x7F\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]*', subst_utf8))
end

print(processstring("mÜ⌠⌠í∩"))  --> MUFFIN
```

Comment: When trying to run this I get a malformed pattern error on line 12
`for utf8letter in list_of_letters:gmatch'[\0-\x7F\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]*' do`

Comment: Thanks so much @EgorSkriptunoff ! If it's not abusive on my part would you mind explaining what goes on in your code? I don't quite understand what you did around lines 11-15 and 18. Are those regular expressions you've used for sorting?

Comment: @Arengorn - Symbol may be longer that 1 byte.  Lines 11-15: Splitting your strings into separate symbols and creating an associative array with "substitution rules".  Line 18: Splitting a user string into separate symbols and make substitution of each symbol according to your rules.

Comment: Quite interesting, I'd never have thought of this approach! In lines 12 and 18 you make use of `'[%z\1-\x7F\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]*'`. Am I correct to reference [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) to understand those?

Comment: Yes, patterns are very handy in Lua ;-)

Comment: I'll certainly look further into it! Thanks so much for your help and patience Egor.